# Android Recycler view adapter refill

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How I can clear and refill RecyclerView adapter from the same class(within the same adapter) without using events?

Answer (score 0):

you can clear list source adapter or call setAdapter again...

Answer (score 0):

In your class, set the adapter with the new list of data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

For ex,

```
mAdapter.setData(data); //pass new list of data string
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In your Adapter class,

```
MyAdapter(final Context context, ArrayList<String> data) { //Constructor
    mData = data;
}

void setData(final ArrayList<String> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}
```

Hope this helps!